# perl hash not reading from param ()

Tags: perl, cgi, param

I cannot get perl to read a hash key that was passed to it from param().

this does not work.

```
append_file('pending_entries.txt',$spanish_url{param('venue')});
```

nor this,

```
my $var = $spanish_url{param('venues')};
append_file( 'pending_entries.txt', $var ) ;
```

nor this

```
my $ven = param('venue');
my $var = $spanish_url{$ven};
append_file( 'pending_entries.txt', $var ) ;
```

but this does.

```
append_file('pending_entries.txt',$spanish_url{'key'});
```

please help.

Comment: You said nothing about what is `%spanish_url` and what is excepted to be in `param('venue')`. I bet you just not receiving parameter somehow.

Comment: Make sure you check the value of param('venues') in the debugger.  This can be done with the x command in the debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried printing the value in the param to see what it is? Hash keys must be exact. Probably you have something like `key\n` or `Key` in your param. The [`Data::Dumper`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3a%3aDumper) module (core module in perl 5) is very good for such debugging. E.g.:

```
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
print Dumper param('venue');
```

Comment: I tried to print param('venue') by itself and it does print out the correct value. 'venue' is a popup_menu that takes its values from a .txt file. i used chomp on the values taken from that file so i don't think it is a stray newline. I tried TLP's advice and i get `$VAR1 = undef;` which makes me think it has to do with the way im assigning values to the hash.

Comment: Well, now you know how to debug it. It is hard for me to tell what you are doing wrong without seeing the code.